# Auto backup encrypted in zip file

Tags: mysql, encryption, backup

I take backup my database using

```
mysqldump -u nollyvenon -p caretime> caretime.
sql && cipher /e /a caretime.sql
```

but I want to autobackup the database in an encrypted zip file

I want to run as in scheduler in windows server

Answer (score 0):

you did not specify the platform, but if i assume its *nix, then below solution might work for you

Auto backup : Using **Crontab**

sample command :

```
 crontab -u username -e
* * * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD DB | gzip > FILENAME
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

This might help someone.

```
mysqldump --force --opt -u nollyvenon -pnollyboy caretime> c:\caretime.sql && cipher /e /a c:\caretime.sql

call openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in c:\caretime.sql -out c:\caretime2.sql -pass pass:hello

call gzip c:\caretime2.sql
```